# How to choose a Photo Selector?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want the user be able to choose an avatar for himself. I implement selecting an image like this:

```
PhotoChooserTask photoChooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
photoChooser.Completed += photoChooser_Completed;
photoChooser.Show();
```

But after this, I want to show a one cell grid, and user can zoom in and out the picture to locate a part of image which wants be in the avatar. just like Instagram apps or WhatsApp.

How can I implement this second part? any reference or any example is appreciated. thanks

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678268/how-to-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-images-in-wp7) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969400/pinch-to-zoom-functionality-in-windows-phone-8) this may helps you

Comment: are you asking like selecting the thumbnail view for facebook profile pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [PixelHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask.pixelheight%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [PixelWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask.pixelwidth%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) properties of the `PhotoChooserTask` before calling `Show`. The user will then be able to crop the image to the dimensions set.

```
PhotoChooserTask photoChooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
photoChooser.PixelHeight = 100;
photoChooser.PixelWidth = 100;
photoChooser.Completed += photoChooser_Completed;
photoChooser.Show();
```

Comment: WOOWW man, in my career I never shocked like this! that is great

Comment: great !! I missed to set these simple properties :)

Answer (score 0):

For the "locating a part of the image" question, i think this will help

[Getting a particular Portion of Image (Picture)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842676/getting-a-particular-portion-of-image-picture)

Display the image inside a rectangle and you can cut out only the part that appears inside the rectangle.

Comment: `Bitmap` and so `Clone` isn't supported in Windows Phone